# Force TypeScript Array to contain an element of given value

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I'm trying to force an argument of type `number[]` to contain at least one element of value `9`.

So far I've got:

```
type MyType<Required> = { 0: Required } | { 1: Required } | { 2: Required };

declare function forceInArray<
    Required extends number,
    Type extends number[] & MyType<Required>
>(
    required: Required,
    input: Type
): void;

// should fail type-checking
forceInArray(9, []);
forceInArray(9, [1, 2]);
forceInArray(9, { 0: 9 });

// should type-check correctly
forceInArray(9, [9]);
forceInArray(9, [9, 9]);
forceInArray(9, [9, 2, 3, 4]);
forceInArray(9, [1, 9, 3, 4]);
forceInArray(9, [1, 2, 9, 4]);
forceInArray(9, [1, 2, 3, 9]);
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB4BKECOBXAlgJwgBMA+KAXigG8oAGALinW3yKgF8oAfKqARgaa4Chdlx4AmAZiGs2AbgCwAKGWEIAYwA2AQwJQAZlgB264DgD2Rg+bzqIASSMBBPHm0hkyqN8bSWIiAAPYAgjQgBnKCMsAFsAIwg8ABovH0RIKCCQsMjo+MSAbQBdKAAyWAQkND9hYmViAApU7wJmYSk2ohSlHygcIzAsYAZ0iGUASgYAN3McQkUVJQB6JahwgAtzLE0RfW0cTShQSABadXWNAGt+gHNlfRs7Rxc3EAaATiSoYvGFh9sHM5XO4Pl8CrwvuIir97o9AS8QZ8ePQoO92DDFis1pttiJjhAzhd1JcoOobARTJoQLCAc9gW8kQV3tC-nC6a9Qd8kcyMf8nkCOYykeIvgBmL4AFhZNP5CIZYIhqLFkulSj58PpnPBkK+SKlvLZAsRCp1UHFqJZQA)

But ofc the type `MyType` won't include all possible indexes, so I'm trying to write that in some other way. `{ [index: number]: 9}` is not the good way to do that, since it requires **all** values to be set to `9`. I've also tried some combination of mapped types, with no success

How can I write `MyType` so that it solves this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use mapped types.  Here's how I'd type `forceInArray()`:

```
declare function forceInArray<
  R extends number,
  T extends number[],
>(required: R, input: [...T] extends { [K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: R } }[number] ?
  readonly [...T] : never): void;
```

Some of the complexity here has to do with convincing the compiler to infer array literal values as tuple types and number literal values as numeric literal types (having `[...T]` in there deals with both).  There's some [black magic involved](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680).  Also I'd expect some interesting edge cases to crop up around widened types like `number`, 0-element tuples, etc.  Finally, I used `readonly` arrays so people can use [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) if they want (as in `forceInArray(9, [1,2,9] as const)`).

Okay, the heart of the matter: `{ [ K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: R } }[number]` type is very much like your `MyType` type alias.  If `T` is `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and `R` is `9`, then that type becomes `[{0: 9}, {1: 9}, {2: 9}, {3: 9}, {4: 9}][number]`, or `{0: 9} | {1: 9} | {2: 9} | {3: 9} | {4: 9}`.  Notice how it expands to have as many terms as the length of `T`.

Let's see if it works:

```
forceInArray(9, []); // error
forceInArray(9, [1, 2]); // error
forceInArray(9, { 0: 9 }); // error

forceInArray(9, [9]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [9, 9]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [9, 2, 3, 4]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [1, 9, 3, 4]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [1, 2, 9, 4]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [1, 2, 3, 9]); // okay
forceInArray(9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]); // okay
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxjBAElUBBGGKATwB4BYAKHngCV4QAPDEVYAM7xUyALYAjEDAA0zVgBVOPPoOFjJMANoBdWUwB8ACjgBHZFjjAAXO2nwsqAA7IMNzQDpP87Ut78hAN7wmgDS9vgA1iA0OIjw3jZBmgAK4fAh2jYcAL7w2ZoiElI+APxy8HBQwHgQNMGe7t7wNqggAG5SAJQ2bThYwADczMyIhMRklNQ0hgCcdjqdA-AA9MucVIQjY6QUVLSz8wCMdgBM2osra1Iwm0yjRDuT+3PwQQAMNjN5F6vrNzDDO7bCZ7aYvTQzc5LX44CK0LYPEFTA7BF6Qn5rWHwoGI3bI8EvE52ADMdgALFDLvAsTQEeM8c8jnYXqT4BSMdS4bScfSnmCmfAifAXuzoZiuXTHqCUZpjoKSczKTCJTypfj5m87HKhayyXYAKx2ABsdgA7HYAByKjk05hAA)

Comment: A comment about the `| [R]` part: This pattern was [mentioned at least once by Hejlsberg himself here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990). See also the [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891863/2707792).

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing this awesome solution. How can I define a similar requirement for an array (without a function declaration). I would like to make this work: `const myList: ArrayWithForcedItem<'bar'> = ['foo', 'bar']`. If I try to use your solution I still need to define the generic types explicitly every time:
`const y: ArrayForcedItem<'bar', ["bar", "house", "mouse"]> = ["bar", "house", "mouse"]`

Comment: I started using it 10 months ago and it worked like a charm but now with TS v4.8.x it doesn't work anymore (error about circular dependency of `T`). Can you provide an update to this that works with more recent versions?

Comment: Okay, done... it's a little more roundabout since you have to replace the type parameter constraint with a conditional type in the function parameter type but it still works, I think