# mapped tuple types / array: pass array as tuple to a function

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

What I want to do is pass an array to a function and receive the values of this array as a tuple in another function.

```js
myFunction(
    (a, b) => null,
    {
        params: [true, 1]
    }
);
```

In the example above, I want typings: `a: boolean` and `b: number`. Instead I receive `a: boolean | number` and `b: boolean | number`.

Please keep in mind that I want the length of params to be variable. Also `[1, false, 'string', {}]` should be possible.

As I have read this has something to do with [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25947)? But I really don't get it.

My current implementation looks like this:

```js
function myFunction<P extends any[]>(
    fn: (...params: P) => null, 
    options: { params: P }) {
    ...
}
```

--

What actually works is this:

```js
myFunction(
    (a, b) => null,
    {
        params: [true, 1] as [boolean, number]
    }
);
```

But I really don't want to type-cast all the time to make it work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

There is actually an easier way. Normally narrowing of an array to a tuple type is only possible by the caller of a function with `as const` (see original answer). We can move this responsibility to the generic type parameter `P` of function `myFunction` by [including a tuple type as constituent of an uniontype](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990), so the constraint now becomes `P extends (ReadonlyArray<any> | readonly [any])`.

```
function myFunction<P extends (ReadonlyArray<any> | readonly [any])>(
  fn: (...params: P) => null,
  options: { params: P }
) {
  fn(...options.params)
  // ...
}

myFunction((a, b) => null, {
  params: [true, 1]
});

// params: [boolean, number]
// fn: (a: boolean, b: number) => null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPABUQFMAPKIsAEwGdEAKAJSIENKEAbVAQQCcfnUuZmFQA+RAB9EPFmzCdEAbQC6ASlF0AUIkTAwALnoA6EwAdm-ZNUP5ViALziwIduwA02xHFOwE1xADeiOaW-oQAvpp2AZ56dCZG3r5g1EYhzFaqngD02YgJmpGaaJiQyXR0zG6IAEZ2jojOrtUxOulWhopQPCBE1QCMyoWqANyaQA)

Credit goes to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956812/force-typescript-array-to-contain-an-element-of-given-value) by jcalz involving some "sorcery code"  I picked up here. Also have a look at the relevant [feature suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680).

#### Original answer:

Although I don't quite understand your use case, what about this?

```
// fn: (params_0: true, params_1: 1, params_2: Date) => null
myFunction((a, b) => null, {
  params: ([true, 1, new Date()]) as const
}); 

function myFunction<P extends readonly any[]>(
  fn: (...params: P) => null,
  options: { params: P }
) { fn(...options.params); }
```

You still use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), but don't have to manually write all tuple item types. I assume, you just pass on your `params` directly to the callback, as there would be no way to manipulate `P` inside `myFunction` body in a way, where you rely on the tuple item types, as `P` is only constrained to extend `any[]`.

In general initialized arrays are widened to `Array` type by the compiler if you don't narrow them at initialization time with `as const`.

```
const options = {
  params: [3,4,"a"] // params: (string | number)[];
}

const optionsConst = {
  params: [3,4,"a"] as const // params: readonly [3, 4, "a"];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPABUQFMAPKIsAEwGdEAnIgQ0oQBtVFGxUBtAXQB8ACgBQiRMDAAuREIB0CgA6M6jZNRn4AlIgC8AxGBCtWAGjGI4i2Ag2IA3omWr1mxAF8RO+xcnyFVjZg1HLOatRaFgD0UYgKciKeImiYkEFCQoymiABGOvqGxmYOFmGusjxQdCBE2QCM2WBEAO6IACKM5EJafDqMtBC2UIlaANwiIoPBUJbWOLS6JeJldjwAzKYALKYARIw7fIgxTirhMkLUVTBgAOaIAD6FyDlEdFr840lTl7NB1ADCQz0SxOLlWG22ewOnAGQOOKxkDGYbA462y20QUL4nyAA)

Comment: I updated my examples. I want the length of array to be variable.

Comment: wow, I'm pretty impressed! It just works as you described it. you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration code is correct.

This is the right way to invoke your function:

```js
myFunction<[number, boolean]>(
  (a, b) => null, 
  {params: [1, true]}
);
```

Comment: I updated my examples. I want the length of array to be variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function myFunction<A, B, P extends [A, B]>(
  fn: (...params: P) => null,
  options: { params: P }) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my examples. I want the length of array to be variable.