# Mapping array parameter type to array return type?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum to describe "fields", and a mapping of each field to a type:

```
enum Field {
  Id,
  Position,
  Name,
  Enabled,
}

interface FieldTypes extends Record<Field, any> {
  [Field.Id]: number;
  [Field.Position]: number;
  [Field.Name]: string;
  [Field.Enabled]: boolean;
}
```

I wrote a function to extract a given field from some `data` (which I've defined here as `unknown` type because it's not important for this question):

```
declare function getField<F extends Field>(
  data: unknown,
  field: F
): FieldTypes[F];

const position: number = getField({}, Field.Position);
const name: string = getField({}, Field.Name);
```

This compiles without error. `getField` indeed returns a `number` for `position` and a `string` for `name`.

Now I want to write a `getFields` function that extracts multiple fields from `data` in order, but I'm struggling to define it. Here's how I *expect* it to work:

```
const fields: [boolean, number, number] = getFields({}, [
  Field.Enabled,
  Field.Id,
  Field.Position,
]);
```

So how do I define this function? This is what I tried but it doesn't return the correct type:

```
declare function getFields<F extends Field>(
  data: unknown,
  fields: F[]
): FieldTypes[F][];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
enum Field {
  Id,
  Position,
  Name,
  Enabled,
}

interface FieldTypes extends Record<Field, any> {
  [Field.Id]: number;
  [Field.Position]: number;
  [Field.Name]: string;
  [Field.Enabled]: boolean;
}
```

First we create another `type` which takes an tuple of `Field` and returns an tuple with the corresponding types.

```
type MultipleFieldTypes<T extends readonly Field[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof FieldTypes ? FieldTypes[T[K]] : never
}
```

Then we modify the function `getFields` to accept a tuple of `Field` as the generic type `F`. As the return type we pass `F` to `MultipleFieldTypes`.

```
declare function getFields<F extends Field[]>(
  data: unknown,
  fields: [...F]
): MultipleFieldTypes<F>;
```

Now we have the correct return type:

```
const fields: [boolean, number, number] = getFields({}, [
  Field.Enabled,
  Field.Id,
  Field.Position,
]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEygbwFBSgSWQGiygAUB7AZzgBc5SRDsA5AQwmAagFERmAjRYAQwBfDBjggqwAE4AzZgGNgsBCgAqATwAOwclGAAPKSGR6ASsAWlpyADzwkBKMxAaAfOiIBtBygB0eAC6AFxQ4BC8MgDc3r7IfmSUNHQhYZCR0jHYPqrxLGyp5FTSEgDmWVA5jn7cfALIqbykpAIuMaIYVNrKALJgiDRaAnGaOuS2avpGoKZQ0sDMyHSIGiqOXoEeALye2NkA0lASUADWwBqkslBqqWpe%204FTxrNnF1cj3XoA-Gvqn153B6PUIgYAANxkIjEyEsiGY8ygsjAIAUyRAUFKwCocXGMCeMz0AAoLItlhoAILSaTMDT2XIeAA%20cwWSxAK0qcUCAEo3ISiMhmFRmKFkScQKQAO70IiyXLkUIwDBc0J9AZwIbAD5jexuGJiKwgIqIuWhLxNFoLehpCIyfDWjKPHaY7FywloYR2rxEOI1Hj8QQcH14QO5BIUai0aXcqJAA)

Comment: What is up with the `(ReadonlyArray<Field> | readonly [Field])`? Isn't there a more concise way of expressing a generic tuple and why is a singular tuple `[Field]` involved?

Comment: This is a "work-around" so that the caller does not have to use `as const` and typescript recognizes it not as an `array` but as a tuple. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57991977/8613630

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would be nice if this would work just out of the box for array literal arguments. Also, I would write it as `(readonly Field[] | readonly [Field])` to not mix different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: thanks @TobiasS. for clarification. also looking at the following answer link you could use [...T] for tuple infer. this way getFields get `<F extends Field[]>`  and fields becomes `fields: [...F]`
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66953684/9238134

Comment: @buzatto thanks. That definitely looks cleaner