# TypeScript: Meaning of `| [T]`-constraint for compile-time checks of element membership in arrays

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, mapped-types

I want to write a function `f` that accepts a single argument of type `A`, where `A` must be an array that contains an element of a certain type `T`. For simplicity, assume that `T = 'ok'` (singleton type of the string `'ok'`).

Using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57958451/2707792), I obtained the following preliminary solution:

```
function f<
  E,
  A extends (ReadonlyArray<E> | [E]) & {[K in keyof A]: {[T in K]: 'ok'}}[number]
>(a: A) {}
```

As in the answer quoted above, it indeed works.

But I could not make any sense of the `| [E]`-part, so I decided to check whether I can remove it, or replace it by yet another type:

```
function f<
  E, 
  X, 
  A extends (ReadonlyArray<E> | [X]) & {[K in keyof A]: {[T in K]: 'ok'}}[number]
>(a: A) {}
```

This also works, i.e. it can differentiate between arrays with or without element `'ok'`:

```
f(['a', 'b', 'ok', 'z']) // compiles, good
f(['a', 'b', 'z'])       // does not compile, good
```

My problem is that I can't understand why it doesn't work if I remove the `[X]` part. It seems completely unrelated to anything what's going on in the code:

- Arity of `[X]` does not match the arity of the tuples
- The type `X` isn't actually tied to anything, it has no bounds containing either `E` or `A` or `string` or `'ok'` or anything else.

What is the `| [X]` doing, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's  take a simple example:

```
function foo<T extends number[]>(t: T): T { return t }
foo([1, 2, 3]) // number[]
```

will have an array return type inferred.

```
function foo2<T extends number[] | [number]>(t: T): T { return t }
foo2([1, 2, 3]) // [number, number, number]
```

`| [number]` [*forces* TypeScript to infer a *tuple*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) instead of an array, without using `as const` (a hidden compiler rule, if you will).

You can even keep the number literals narrow by adding a type parameter `R` for the array items extending a primitive type:

```
function foo3<R extends number, T extends R[] | [R]>(t: T): T { return t }
foo3([1, 2, 3]) // [1, 2, 3]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEwQBbAI2wCcBtAXQD4AKKALkQwEpusAb0R1sUEHSRREAXwBQKOGwYBGADSIATBoDMTXogD0h8lVqMmcheGjwkizZhz5CpUzXrNEAH0QMKHnSsHAL8PIjCouKSiNLyDsrqWrr6Rib%20ZvQaAebZmUFWoJCwCMioOmgASs4ExGQ5WeF4tW6VXr4MlcFcPGFCImISUrIK5Yka2oh6BsZ%20SZN6QA)

Comment: "a hidden compiler rule" - Does this hidden rule have any informal name, or is it mentioned in any kind of official documentation anywhere?

Comment: It is not part of the official TS handbook, but has been mentioned by language creator Anders Hejlsberg himself in a GitHub issue as valid workaround. So we can assume, it is here to stay in the compiler. I would need to search the concrete issue again, link not at hand currently.

Comment: Did you mean this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422911925 ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Especially the one comment before: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990

Comment: Could you then link it more prominently in your answer, just so it's obvious that it's something that Hejlsberg himself approved of? (alternatively, I could edit the link into your answer, if you don't mind)